# build error on Keil uVision5 compiling FreeRTOS v8.1.2 with cmsis

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32, keil, freertos

I use Keil uvision5 to compile cmsis_os.c (wrapper for my FreeRTOS).

I get this this error:
..\Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\GCC\ARM_CM4F\portmacro.h(221): error:  #18: expected a ")"

portmacro.h has this:

```
portFORCE_INLINE static void vPortRaiseBASEPRI( void )
{
    uint32_t ulNewBASEPRI;

    __asm volatile
    (
        "   mov %0, %1                                              \n" \
        "   msr basepri, %0                                         \n" \
        "   isb                                                     \n" \
        "   dsb                                                     \n" \
        :"=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY )    <<<<<<<<<<< LINE WITH THE ERROR.
    );
}
```

ARM is STM32F417VG.
FreeRTOS source code is V8.1.2

We have existing gcc-based source code for our ARM that I need to port onto Keil IDE.
I used ST CubeMx to generate a virgin Keil project.
Then, I added v8.1.2 FreeRTOS source code, including cmsis_os.c and cmsis_os.h because Keil needs cmsis RTOS wrapper for debugger etc.

Comment: _"I cannot find ulNewBASEPRI anywhere."_ - modulo broken formatting, it's declared right there as a local variable... Either way, that's some GCC-specific syntax and functionality, so compiling it with not-GCC is going to mean rewriting it. FreeRTOS claims to support the Keil tools directly, so why do you need to mess with the GCC version of the sources anyway?

Answer (score 0):

With Keil you should use appropriate files from `FreeRTOS\Source\portable\RVDS\ARM_CM4F\`

This function in Keil syntax looks like

```
static portFORCE_INLINE void vPortRaiseBASEPRI( void )
{
    uint32_t ulNewBASEPRI = configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY;
    __asm
    {
        msr basepri, ulNewBASEPRI
        dsb
        isb
    }
}
```